# JSON Schema validate if a number is either zero or more than 1000

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

How could I write a schema to validate that an `integer` field is either `0` or more than `100`?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Have you looked into composition anyOf, type constraints and constraints that you can set on numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can check equality with the `const` keyword: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#constant-values

You can check numerical ranges with the `maximum`, `minimum`, `exclusiveMaximum` and `exclusiveMinimum` keywords: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html

You can combine schemas with a number of keywords: `anyOf`, `allOf`, `oneOf`, `not`, and `if`/`then`/`else`: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html